# How do I change the purchase quantity on my bigcartel shop to be a text box

Tags: e-commerce, bigcartel

I sell fabric by the 10cm increment. How do I change the purchase quantity on my bigcartel shop to be a text box to allow customer to type in the quantity they'd like to buy (for example 1.2 metres) instead of using bigcartel's dropdown purchase quantities?

At the moment, I end up having a long list of drop down options ie. 10cm, 20cm, 30cm, 40cm, 50cm, 60cm, 70cm, 80cm, 90cm, 1m. And then I have to rely on the customer adding the quantities they want together to get the total they need (ie. 20cm and 1m to get 1.2 metres). People sometimes make a mistake with their math and order the wrong amount. I would prefer to be able to just have a text box in the purchase quantity area where my customer could simply type in "1.2" and the quantity and price would be calculated for the cart.

Is this possible on bigcartel? I know it is possible on a lot of other e-commerce sites. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not a way to add an input box to your product or cart pages to allow for customer input like that, sorry! Your customers can only select their option from a list that you create in the admin.